# How to use href link to checked in option?

Tags: php, wordpress, href, location-href

I refer to this website: gesher-jds.org/giving-tuesday

When I click on "Donate now" the href works and it gets to the right place, same works for the "Donate Now, Pay Later" option.

But I do want that when I click on Donate Now, pay later option, It will also check the pay later option that is below and will open the other form. How do I do it? I still want it to go to the same location, but to also to check the pay later option and show the other form.

Thanks!

```
<?php /*  template name: Custom Form */ ?>
<?php get_header();?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="gesher-sections">
                <div class="gesher-section">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <h1><?php if (get_field('alternate_title')) the_field('alternate_title'); else the_title();?></h1>
                                        <div class="image-div">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="gesher-content">
                                            <?php the_content();?>
                                            <div class="new-goal-form">
                                                <div class="donations">
                                                    <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                                                        <div class="multiplier col-lg-5">
                                                            <div class="whitebox">
                                                                <div class="heading">Your Donation</div>
                                                                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                                                                    <div class="col-md-2 costed">$ <div>USD</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" id="sample-donation"/></div>
                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="finaldonation">
                                                                <span>With Each Donation</span>
                                                                Gesher Jewish Day School Gets
                                                                <div class="multiplyresult">$0.00</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1">Donate Now</a>

                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-2 seperator">
                                                            OR
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-5 multi-pay multiplier">
                                                         <div class="whitebox">
                                                                <div class="heading">Your Donation</div>
                                                                <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                                                                    <div class="col-md-2 costed">$ <div>USD</div></div>
                                                                    <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" id="sample-donation2"/></div>
                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="finaldonation">
                                                                <span>With Each Donation</span>
                                                                Gesher Jewish Day School Gets
                                                                <div class="multiplyresult2">$0.00</div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>


<!--<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Please Fill Following Information If You Want To Pay Later</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="2703" title="Pay Later Form"]'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>-->
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <div name="myAnchor" id="myAnchor">
                                                <?php
                                                    $valueform = get_field( "form_short_code" );
                                                    echo do_shortcode($valueform);
                                                ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 statstics">
                                        <div class="time-remaining">
                                            <h5>Time Remaining</h5>
                                            <div class="clockit">
                                                <div class="row bt">
                                                    <div class="col-6" id="days"></div>
                                                    <div class="col-6" id="hours"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row tb">
                                                    <div class="col-6" id="minutes"></div>
                                                    <div class="col-6" id="seconds"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="dot"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php $valueid = get_field("form_id"); ?>
                                        <?php echo do_shortcode('[give_goal id="'.$valueid.'" show_text="true" show_bar="true"]') ?>
                                        <div class="goalcompletion">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div>

<div class="donors_info">
<div class="totalenteries"></div>
<?php
    $valueid = 2727;
    //Get donors based on forms IDs (can be single or multiple forms)
    if(function_exists('give_get_payments')) {
        $args = array(
            'give_forms' => $valueid,
            'number' => -1,
        );
        $donations = give_get_payments( $args );

        echo "<table id='dtab'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<th align='center'>" . 'Name' . "</th>";
        echo "<th align='center'>" . 'Amount' . "</th>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        $donors = array();
        $dtmp=array(); //tmp array
        foreach($donations as $donation) {
            //Now get donor information from this donation ("customer" aka "donor")
            $customer_id = give_get_payment_customer_id( $donation->ID );
            $customers  = new Give_Customer( $customer_id );
            $nameis = $customers->name;

            $amt = get_post_meta($donation->ID,'_give_payment_total',false);
            $donationAll = 0;
            foreach ($amt as $key => $value) { 
                $donationAll = $donationAll + $value;
            }
            //Write a tmp array with name as key and donation as value
            if(array_key_exists($nameis,$dtmp)) {
                //name already exists -> add donation value
                $dtmp[$nameis] = $dtmp[$nameis] + $donationAll;
            } else {
                //name is not in the array -> new array: key name -> donation
                $dtmp[$nameis] = $donationAll;
            }

            $donors[] = $nameis;
        }

        foreach ($dtmp as $key => $value) {
            //iterate the tmp array
            echo "<tr class='select'>";
            echo "<td align='left'>" . $key . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $purchaseis = "$" . $value . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
    }   
?>
</div>


                                        <div class="time-remaining">
                                            <h5>Share With Your Friends</h5>
                                            <div class="slinks">
                                                <a onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'Facebook Share', 'width=400,height=400')" target="popup" class="thisa" href="javascript:"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> </a>
                                                <a onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'Twitter Share', 'width=400,height=400')" class="thisa" target="popup" href="javascript:"> <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i> </a>
                                                <a onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'Linked In Share', 'width=400,height=400')" class="thisa" target="popup" href="javascript:"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i> </a>
                                                <a onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'Google Plus Share', 'width=400,height=400')" class="thisa" target="_blank" href="javascript:"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-square"></i> </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; endif;?>


<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var donationPercentage = jQuery('.give-progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow');
if (donationPercentage < 26){
    jQuery(".goalcompletion").html('<img src="https://www.gesher-jds.org/wp-content/themes/gesher/img/goal1.png" class="img-responsive" />');
}else if (donationPercentage > 25 || donationPercentage < 51){
    jQuery(".goalcompletion").html('<img src="https://www.gesher-jds.org/wp-content/themes/gesher/img/goal2.png" class="img-responsive" />');
}else if (donationPercentage > 50 || donationPercentage < 76){
    jQuery(".goalcompletion").html('<img src="https://www.gesher-jds.org/wp-content/themes/gesher/img/goal3.png" class="img-responsive" />');
}else if (donationPercentage > 75 || donationPercentage < 100){
    jQuery(".goalcompletion").html('<img src="https://www.gesher-jds.org/wp-content/themes/gesher/img/goal4.png" class="img-responsive" />');
}else if (donationPercentage == 100){
    jQuery(".goalcompletion").html('<img src="https://www.gesher-jds.org/wp-content/themes/gesher/img/goal5.png" class="img-responsive" />');
}
});
</script>   

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
    var table = jQuery('#dtab').DataTable({
        "paging":   false,
        "info":   false,
         "scrollY":        "400px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
    });
    var trows = table.rows( '.select' ).count();
    jQuery(".totalenteries").html(trows + ' DONORS DONATED TO THIS CAUSE');

    jQuery("#sample-donation").keyup(function(){
        var keyValue = jQuery(this).val()*2;
        var keyValueOriginal = jQuery(this).val();
        console.log(keyValue);
        jQuery(".multiplyresult").html("$"+keyValue + ".00");



        if ( jQuery('#give-amount').length > 0 ) {
                jQuery('#give-amount')
                    .val(keyValueOriginal)
                    .trigger('blur');
        }

        /*jQuery("#give-amount").attr("value" , keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery("#give-amount").attr("data-amount" , keyValueOriginal);
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").html(keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").attr("data-total" , keyValueOriginal);
        jQuery("input[name=give-price-id]").val(0);*/
    });
    jQuery('.anchor2').click(function(){
        jQuery('#give-card-number-wrap-2676 input').removeAttr('required');
        jQuery('#give-card-cvc-wrap-2676 input').removeAttr('required');
        jQuery('#give-card-name-wrap-2676 input').removeAttr('required');
        jQuery('.card-expiration input').removeAttr('required');
        jQuery('#give_cc_fields-2676').hide();
    });
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(".give-donation-level-btn").on('click tap touchstart', function () {
            var amount=$(this).val();
            //var amountarr = amount.split(".");
            //amount = amountarr[0];
            $('#sample-donation').val(amount);
            var keyValue = $(this).val()*2;
            var keyValueOriginal = $(this).val();
            console.log(keyValue);
            $(".multiplyresult").html("$"+keyValue + ".00");
            /*alert(keyValueOriginal);

            $("#give-amount").attr("value" , keyValueOriginal + ".00");
            $("#give-amount").attr("data-amount" , keyValueOriginal);
            $(".give-final-total-amount").html(keyValueOriginal + ".00");
            $(".give-final-total-amount").attr("data-total" , keyValueOriginal);*/
        });

    });
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(jQuery.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
//jQuery('#give-donation-level-button-wrap').insertBefore('.donations');

} );
</script>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php the_field('donation_timer'); ?>").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
     document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = "<b>" + days +"</b>" + " Days";
     document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "<b>" + hours +"</b>" + " Hours";
     document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = "<b>" + minutes +"</b>" + "  Mins";
     document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = "<b>" + seconds +"</b>" + " Sec";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

<<script>   jQuery("#sample-donation2").keyup(function(){
        var keyValue = jQuery(this).val()*2;
        var keyValueOriginal = jQuery(this).val();
        console.log(keyValue);
        jQuery(".multiplyresult2").html("$"+keyValue + ".00");
        jQuery("#give-amount").attr("value" , keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery("#give-amount").attr("data-amount" , keyValueOriginal);
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").html(keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").attr("data-total" , keyValueOriginal);

                if ( jQuery('#give-amount').length > 0 ) {
                jQuery('#give-amount')
                    .val(keyValueOriginal)
                    .trigger('blur');
        }

        /*jQuery("#give-amount").attr("value" , keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery("#give-amount").attr("data-amount" , keyValueOriginal);
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").html(keyValueOriginal + ".00");
        jQuery(".give-final-total-amount").attr("data-total" , keyValueOriginal);
        jQuery("input[name=give-price-id]").val(0);*/

    });
</script>
<style>
ul#give-donation-level-button-wrap li:last-child {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues here I think. For starters, both the buttons have an id of "anchor1" whereas id's should be unique on a page.

If you rename the second one to "anchor2" you can achieve this with something like:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#anchor2').on('click', function() {
            jQuery('input[name="payment-mode"][value="offline"]').prop("checked", true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, you have some non-matching class selectors + I think there are some generated id's here, which you want to avoid using as they are likely to change. For example you have this click handler:

```
    jQuery('.anchor2').click(function(){
        jQuery('#give-card-number-wrap-2676 input').removeAttr('required');
        jQuery('#give-card-cvc-wrap-2676 input').removeAttr('required');
        jQuery('#give-card-name-wrap-2676 input').removeAttr('required');
        jQuery('.card-expiration input').removeAttr('required');
        jQuery('#give_cc_fields-2676').hide();
    });
```

which won't fire as there isn't an element with class "anchor2" and also won't match as there are no elements *-2676.

Comment: Thanks! So can I add the first code and rename the second one to Anchor 2? And where should I add the code? And I don't think I need the second code (I know it's there), but I can delete it.

Comment: You can add that near the other <script> tags on the page towards the bottom. Maybe place it after a closing script tag (</script>)

Comment: I will test it. Thanks!

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work. I added the script and changed <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1">Donate Now, Pay Later</a> to  <a href="#Anchor2" rel="" id="anchor1">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Leave the href as it is, and change the id. Like this: <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1">Donate Now, Pay Later</a> to <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor2">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I changed to: <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor2">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>    It changed the button and it didn't get to the "pay later" option.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the page: gesher-jds.org/giving. When I tested it there It didn't work .

Comment: I'm seeing <a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1">Donate Now, Pay Later</a> on that page

Comment: Yes, but when I change it via Inspect element, It doesn't work. The button is not right and it doesn't link.

Comment: Ah, I think jQuery won't fire for a change like that via dev tools as the event handler has already been registered. The button loses it's styling as the CSS is for the id of anchor1 - that should really be a class as id's should be unique.

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: Try changing that id in the source as opposed to in dev tools + see if that works. Then give the buttons a classname and apply the CSS from #anchor1 to the new class in styles.css

Comment: It did check the other button but it didn't replace the form. It still shows the first form when It does it.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer:

First thing to do: rename the radio button "Pay Later" ID to a unique one:

```
<li class="give-gateway-option-selected">
    <input type="radio" name="payment-mode" class="give-gateway" id="give-gateway-offline-2727-2" value="offline">
    <label for="give-gateway-offline-2727-2" class="give-gateway-option" id="give-gateway-option-offline"> Pay Later</label>
</li>
```

And then update the "Donate Now, Pay Later" link code like this:

```
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" onclick="document.getElementById('give-gateway-offline-2727-2').click();">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>
```

If you want that click event on the other button, too: change the HTMl link code of the "Donate Now" Button to this:

```
<a href="#myAnchor" rel="" id="anchor1" onclick="document.getElementById('give-gateway-offline-2727-1').click();">Donate Now</a>
```

There are some errors in your code but it is working this way.

Regards Tom

Comment: Thanks! Where should I add this line? Or should I just edit the current one?

Comment: This is the HTML link code for the "Donate Now, Pay Later" Link. Just replace this line with your old one (and keep a backup of the original code). It changes the radio button, removes a css class on the first radio and adds a class to the 2nd radio. But I cant test it and I`m not sure if the form actually changes.

Comment: I will test it. Thanks!

Comment: It did change but the form doesn't change. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Tom! Where should I edit the first code? I can't find it in my file. Do I need to add it?

Comment: The first code comes from your form and is added by the shortcode "echo do_shortcode($valueform);". Can you edit the form in the backend somewhere?
Just give that 2nd radio box the ID: give-gateway-offline-2727-2

Comment: Do you know what the file name is? Trying to find it.

Comment: I never used givewp, but I think you can edit the forms in your dashboard -> Donations -> All Forms. Maybe you can edit the ID of the radio button somewhere there.

Comment: This is generated by javascript propably. The problem is: the ids are not unique. There is no option for this in the dashboard where this form is managed?

Comment: Nope. Trying to find it using Notepad +++ but can't find it.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Best would be if you ask in the Wordpress givewp support forums how to assign unique IDs to input fields. The code works if I change the IDs and the link codes locally in my browser.

Comment: I asked there. I hope they will answer soon. I found this code somewhere:      if ( true === $is_payment_method_visible ) {
      ?>
      <li<?php echo $checked_class; ?>>
       <input type="radio" name="payment-mode" class="give-gateway"
              id="give-gateway-<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway_id . '-' . $id_prefix ); ?>"
              value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway_id ); ?>"<?php echo $checked; ?>>

Answer (score 0):

You messed up some aspects:

- some IDs are given multiple times (anchor1 is set two times and anchor2 is missing in HTML, but in JS you're only using anchor2 and anchor1 is missing)
- in your javascript you refer to your IDs as classes (you use the element ID in HTML but use it as element class in your script, in jQuery: "#" => refering to IDs and "." => refering to classes

Some code to show you how to manipulate radios:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-donate', function(e) {
 $('input:radio[name="payment-mode"]')
  .filter('[value="' + $(e.target).attr('id') + '"]')
   .prop('checked', true);

        // Do your animation stuff
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="#myAnchor" class="btn-donate" id="now">Donate Now</a>
  <a href="#myAnchor" class="btn-donate" id="later">Donate Now, Pay Later</a>
</p>
<div name="myAnchor">
    <input type="radio" name="payment-mode" value="now" /> Pay now
    <input type="radio" name="payment-mode" value="later" /> Pay later
</div>
```

Comment: So do I need to fix my code? Or can I just add the code that you added and change small things?

Comment: You need to fix your whole code, there's a lot of things you actually don't need. Just copy&paste will never work, try to understand my code and change it as you need. Your ids and classes are not consistent and their names are misleading. You'll never understand your code again in future!